# How can packages be unhidden when using only stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'd like to try out the `Writer` monad in ghci.  As advised [here](https://www.stackage.org/install), I tried to use only stack to manage GHC and packages, and avoid a global installation.

From a fresh Ubuntu 15.04 install, after installing stack:

```
stack setup
mkdir lyah && cd lyah
stack new
stack install mtl
stack ghci
ghci> import Control.Monad.Writer
Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Writer’
It is a member of the hidden package ‘mtl-2.1.3.1’.
```

I understand that pre-stack ghc-pkg was used to show/hide packages, but I'm not sure how to proceed here to 'unhide' the mtl package.

Answer (score 18):

Edit the .cabal file `stack new` created and add `mtl` to the `build-depends` section. That part of the file should look like this:

```
build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                   , mtl
```

Then, do a `stack build` before `stack ghci`.

By the way, do not use `stack install` to install libraries - it is merely a shortcut to copy binaries. E.g. `stack install hlint` will first build the package and then copy the resulting binary to *~/.local/bin/*. Instead, always add the packages to the .cabal file, as shown above, and use `stack build` so that they get installed.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement @Jazmit answer. Be aware that your `.cabal` file will have two `build-depends` sections. One under `library:`
and the other under `executable my-project-exec`. In this case, you'd need to put the module under the `executable` section.

Example:

my-project.cabal

```
library: 
  build-depends:
  ...

executable my-project-exe:
  build-depends:
    base >= 4.7 && < 5
    , mtl
```

For further info about library and executable check the docs:
https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-packages.html#editing-the-cabal-file

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `stack`, try adding your packages definition to `dependencies` field in`package.yaml` for expose it into you project.

```yaml
dependencies:
- mtl
```

Then, `stack run`

[Example of `package.yaml`](https://github.com/artileda/ayaka/blob/mastah/package.yaml)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working in GHCi, you can just change the command line passed to the underlying GHC. For example, I did this recently:

```
Prelude> import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk

<no location info>: error:
    Could not load module ‘GI.Gtk’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘gi-gtk-3.0.31’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘gi-gtk’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘gi-gtk-3.0.27’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘gi-gtk’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
Prelude> :set -package gi-gtk-3.0.27
package flags have changed, resetting and loading new packages...
Prelude> import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk
Prelude Gtk>
```